# Drawing logic gates in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to draw solid color logic gates for a schematic design generator, using libGDX. OR gates are particularly difficult because of their irregular shape. I've found great success drawing these gates using the [ShapeRenderer.curve](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html#curve-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-int-) function, but this can only draw lines, not filled in. I'm attempting to draw with [arcs](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html#arc-float-float-float-float-float-), but the end result is too round. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Pixmaps (as opposed to ShapeRenderer) for drawing custom shapes with great success. Unfortunately it is kind of an involved process, but it provides a lot of flexibility to be able to draw whatever shapes you want.

If you are familiar with the pen tool in Photoshop (drawing curves using control points) the BSpline class in LibGDX works in the same way. In my question here I provided sample code which draws a simple curve using BSpline.

[BSpline derivativeAt() method does not return correct value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36257511/bspline-derivativeat-method-does-not-return-correct-value)

Then once you have your complete shape drawn you can use a 'flood fill' algorithm to fill in the shape. Basically you pick a point that is located somewhere in the center of the shape and then the algorithm uses recursion to fill outward until it reaches the edge of the shape. Here is my flood fill code which I removed from my larger class, pulled out unrelated code, and packed it all into one method. This isolated code is untested and hopefully I didn't break it in the process...but this should give the idea of how to do it.

```
public void floodFillShape(Pixmap shapePixmap, int x, int y){
    Array<Vector2> queue = new Array<Vector2>(Vector2.class);
    Color tempColor = new Color();
    Vector2 point;
    queue.add(new Vector2(x, y));

    while (queue.size > 0){
        point = queue.pop();

        if (tempColor.set(shapePixmap.getPixel((int)point.x, (int)point.y)).a == 0){                
            shapePixmap.drawPixel((int)point.x, (int)point.y);              
            queue.add(new Vector2((int)point.x+1, (int)point.y));
            queue.add(new Vector2((int)point.x-1, (int)point.y));
            queue.add(new Vector2((int)point.x, (int)point.y+1));
            queue.add(new Vector2((int)point.x, (int)point.y-1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I've been working with the code you provided in the BSpline question, and I'm not clear on what the "degree" required for BSpline.set is. I am familiar with drawing curves in this style (ShapeRenderer.curve does it pretty much the same).

I've set up what I think should work, based on your example, but the BSpline doesn't appear to be drawing pixels properly. The loop you provided seems to work, as with the failing initial path draw, the loop continued infinitely. Then again, shouldn't it stop once it draws to every pixel in the pixmap?

Comment: For the time being LibGDX BSpline only works with degree 3. Changing the degree changes the math equations used to produce the curve and only the equations for degree 3 have been implemented so far in BSpline. The definition for degree "n" means there are "n+1" control points for each Bezier curve (since BSpline is multiple Bezier curves linked together). For degree 3, each curve has 4 control points (2 end points and 2 that bend the curve). If the flood fill loop goes indefinitely then there must be a gap in the shape. Try drawing the shape without the flood fill, do you see any gaps in it?

Comment: Thanks again! My group needs to focus on other features at this point, so I'll have to put this on hold for now.